# JS execute function if element is loaded - no jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, events

I have an `div` with an id of `doi`, and I want to manipulate it with JavaScript when it is fully loaded (the manipulation uses the dimensions of the images which is not provided in the DOM).

What I tried:

```
document.getElementById('doi').onload = function(){
        console.log('Div of Interest is loaded');
    };
```

This didn't work because the division was probably loaded before I set the Event Handler. So for short, what needs to be done is the following:

- **Check if the element is loaded**

  - if so? -> fire callback function
  - if not? -> set an event handler with callback when fully loaded.

Comment: Might need some sort of timing mechanism to see if the div is in flux or not.

Comment: I don't know what that means :$ - native dutch speaker here

Comment: Go orange! :P Basically what I was saying is perhaps use a setTimeout which monitors the content inside of the div, and when it hasn't changed for a certain amount of time then you can log the loaded message. If it has changed, then recurse the function with the setTimeout to continue monitoring

Comment: Under what conditions is the div considered to be "loaded"?

Comment: Hmm.. i'll keep it in mind. Thx for explaining it ;)

Comment: `div` elements have no `onload` callback, you have two options: manipulate the div after onload is fired on the `document` object or write the js code after the `div` location.

Comment: Clear answer. So there is no way I can easily do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pure javascript: ***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/6a8t9/)***
Using jQuery: ***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/XdXV4/)***

(The demos include some setup which is just filler to show changing content)

To expand on the notion (only in rare cases) of using timers to monitor an element's contents. The content to be observed would more than likely be a combination of its text, html, width, and height. Here is one way to monitor those:

*javascript*

```
function monitor(element,callback){
 var self = element;
 var h = self.clientHeight;
 var w = self.clientWidth;
 var txt = self.innerText;
 var html = self.innerHTML;
 (function flux(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        var done = 
          h == self.clientHeight &&
          w == self.clientWidth &&
          txt == self.innerText &&
          html == self.innerHTML;
        if( done ){
         callback();
        }else{
         h = self.clientHeight;
         w = self.clientWidth;
         txt = self.innerText;
         html = self.innerHTML;
         flux();
        }
    },250);
 })()
};
```

*jQuery extension*

```
$.fn.monitor = function cb(callback){
 var set = this.first();
 var h = set.height();
 var w = set.width();
 var txt = set.text();
 var html = set.html();
 (function flux(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        var done = 
          h == set.height() &&
          w == set.width() &&
          txt == set.text() &&
          html == set.html();
        if( done ){
         if( $.isFunction(callback) )callback();
        }else{
         h = set.height();
         w = set.width();
         txt = set.text();
         html = set.html();
         flux();
        }
    },500);
 })()
};
```

Answer (score 1):

For an image, you can check its `width` property. If it's non-zero, then the image has either loaded, or at least loaded enough that its dimensions are known.

Comment: But not if it is defined in css, true?

Comment: Hm.. gets me hell of a lot closer. But this only seems to apply to images.

Answer (score -1):

You maybe can use the [`transitionend` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/transitionend) if the dimensions are your measurement unit.

Set up a CSS transition for that element (using JS) and bind an event listener to that element. If you use plain JS you have to repeat the `addEventListener` calls with vendor prefixes.

```
#doi {
     -webkit-transition: width 0s linear;
             transition: width 0s linear;
}
```

JS:

```
var afterWidthChange = function( event ) {
    var doi = event.target;

    console.log( 'The width of #doi has changed.', doi );
};

document.getElementById( 'doi' ).addEventListener( 'transitionend', afterWidthChange, false );
document.getElementById( 'doi' ).addEventListener( 'webkitTransitionEnd', afterWidthChange, false );
```

[There is a lib/polyfill for older browsers too.](https://github.com/EvandroLG/transitionEnd/)